# I can't access the '$' alias for querySelector in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In chrome version `45.0.2454.101` and chrome canary `47.0.2525.0`, I get an error when I try to use the `$` alias. Is there a special command to utilize it?

[image]

Comment: Can you link us to a page where this reproduces for you? Unable to reproduce the problem here using an SO page.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a library that redefines `$` to something other than a `function`.

Typing just `$` in the console might give you a hint about which library redefined the variable. If that doesn't help, you could also try the search among script files with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd> +<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.